# Request Scoped Services in ASP.NET 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I'm struggling to get a service to be scoped to the current request in ASP.NET 5.  My start-up code looks like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.AddScoped<IMyService, MyService>();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
  app.UseRequestServices();
  app.UseMiddleware<MyMiddleware>();
}

public class MyMiddleware
{
  RequestDelegate _next;
  IMyService MyService;

  public MyMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, IMyService myService)
  {
    _next = next;
    MyService = myService;
  }

  public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
  {
     --> Here - context.RequestServices does not contain myService
  }
}
```

The IMyService passed to the MyMiddleware constructor does not appear to be request scoped.  It's not being disposed per request and at the point the middleware is invoked it's not registered in `HttpContext.RequestServices`.

Seems like I'm missing something obvious?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, having written out the code in a simpler form I realised what the problem was.

The middleware is not transient/scoped, so dependencies that are scoped need to be passed on the Invoke method rather than the constructor of the middleware.

```
public class MyMiddleware
{
  RequestDelegate _next;

  public MyMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
  {
    _next = next;
  }

  public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context, IMyService myService)
  {
    --> Now working. MyService is registered on context.RequestServices 
  }
}
```